# How to correctly serve my React production build through Django. Currently having MIME type issues with current configuration

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, django, digital-ocean

I'm trying to deploy my react/django web-app to a linux-VM droplet. I'm not using a webpack for the JS content. Instead, I'm serving `npm run build` static files through a CDN sub-domain, digital ocean s3 bucket.

I'm able to `python manage.py collectstatic` which then pushes my react production build folder to the CDN.

When I visit my production website, it currently just loads up a blank page with these console errors:

```
Refused to apply style from 'https://www.my_website_URL.com/static/css/main.ce8d6426.chunk.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

Refused to execute script from 'https://www.my_website_URL.com/static/js/2.ca12ac54.chunk.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

Refused to execute script from 'https://www.my_website_URL.com/static/js/main.220624ac.chunk.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
```

There aren't any network errors that provide any useful information for this matter.

The issue has to be server side (django)... I think.

---

**Project set up:**

[image]

The react production build is inside my core django folder.

Here is how I link my React through django:

`core urls.py`

```
def render_react(request):
    return render(request, "index.html") 
    #index.html being created by react, not django templates 
    
urlpatterns = [
   re_path(r"^$", render_react),
   re_path(r"^(?:.*)/?$", render_react),
   ...
]
```

**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    {% comment %} <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" /> {% endcomment %}
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/chartist.js/latest/chartist.min.css"
    />
    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/chartist.js/latest/chartist.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is installed on a
      user's mobile device or desktop. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    

    <!--
      Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

**settings.py**

```
import os


from pathlib import Path
from decouple import config
import dj_database_url

from datetime import timedelta

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
# BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = config('DJANGO_SECRET_KEY')

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['URL's']

SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True
SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True


INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'rest_framework',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',


    # Third Party Apps #
    'django_filters',
    'corsheaders',
    'django_extensions',
    'drf_yasg',
    'storages',


    # Apps
    'users',
    'bucket',
    'bucket_api',
    
    #oauth
    'oauth2_provider',
    'social_django',
    'drf_social_oauth2',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'oauth2_provider.middleware.OAuth2TokenMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'core.urls'


TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS' : [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'build')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'social_django.context_processors.backends',
                'social_django.context_processors.login_redirect',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'core.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': config('DJANGO_DB_NAME'),
        'USER' : config('DJANGO_DB_ADMIN'),
        'PASSWORD' : config('DJANGO_ADMIN_PASS'),
        'HOST' : config('DJANGO_DB_HOST'),
        'PORT' : config('DJANGO_DB_PORT'),
        'OPTIONS': {'sslmode':'disable'},
    }
}


db_from_env = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=600)
DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)


AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'America/New_York'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = config('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = config('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = config('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME')
AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_URL = config('AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_URL')
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = config('AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN')
AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {
    'CacheControl': 'max-age=86400',
}
AWS_LOCATION = config('AWS_LOCATION')
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = 'public-read'


STATIC_URL = '{}/{}/'.format(AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_URL, AWS_LOCATION)
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'


STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/templates'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'build/static')
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

---

How can I fix my Django to properly serve production static chunk css and js files from my CDN? The pathing and location to CDN have to be correct if the chrome console is able to locate the files within the error.

Please let me know if you need more information from my side. Currently stuck and do not have a simple solution to fix my MIME type errors and solving my website from loading only a blank page.

Thank you for any help/tips/or guidance!

If anyone is wondering, I'm using Gunicorn and Nginx.

EDIT:
added a bounty to draw attention to this question. I am not using Django webpack loader and babel. I would rather not rely on other libraries that could break things easily.

EDIT #2:
I have added my NGINX config file, should I redirect traffic to my CDN path here?

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    return 301 https://my_website_URL.io$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name my_website_URL.com www.my_website_URL.com;

   #  Let's Encrypt parameters
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/my_website_URL.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/my_website_URL.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }




    location / {
        proxy_pass         http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
        proxy_redirect     off;

        proxy_set_header   Host              $http_host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        }
```

EDIT EDIT EDIT:
I have added my gunicorn file because I'm getting a 502 bad gateway and my gunicorn service is giving me this error:

```
● gunicorn.socket - gunicorn socket
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.socket; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: service-start-limit-hit) since Wed 2021-04-28 23:44:16 UTC; 1min 2s ago
   Triggers: ● gunicorn.service
     Listen: /run/gunicorn.sock (Stream)
```

here is my gunicorn config:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=gunicorn.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
User=alpha
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/user/srv/project/backend
ExecStart=/home/user/srv/project/backend/venv/bin/gunicorn \
          --access-logfile - \
          --workers 3 \
          --timeout 300 \
          --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock \
          core.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Check this line ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['URL's'] is it correct ?

Comment: For privacy reasons, I did not disclose this information. What I have in my allowed host are: server IP address, www.url.com, url.com

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Why your app isn't looking for your static files at your CDN

The static file URLs are being generated by React not Django. So even if [`STATIC_URL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#static-url) is set correctly, the URLs to the static files aren't being templated in Django e.g. using [`{% static '' %}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#static-url).

According to your `TEMPLATES` setting Django is serving the built version of `index.html` from `npm run build` (rather than the `index.html` in the question). The `/static` URLs to your CSS and JavaScript files (also built by React) in `index.html` are being generated by React and not Django.

To get React to generate URLs with the correct prefix you can set the [`PUBLIC_URL`](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/advanced-configuration/) environment variable before running `npm run build`. Currently it would be using the default setting (which is the root `/` of the host).

The errors you were receiving would have been an issue if you were serving static files on your host or using `{% static '' %}`. For reference:

#### Why you were getting a MIME type error (urls.py)

One of your URLs is too greedy:

```py
re_path(r"^(?:.*)/?$", render_react),
```

This will match:

```
static/css/main.ce8d6426.chunk.css
```

So that URL will resolve to your `render_react` view and attempt to serve your `index.html` file, hence why it thinks the MIME type is `text/html`:

```
Refused to apply style from 'https://www.my_website_URL.com/static/css/main.ce8d6426.chunk.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
```

If you want to match every URI except those that begin with `static` you could use a negative lookahead in your regular expression:

```py
re_path(r"^(?!static)(?:.*)/?$", render_react),
```

#### Why Django couldn't find your static files (settings.py)

In your settings.py you're overrwriting the `STATIC_URL` setting that directs Django to your CDN for static files:

```py
STATIC_URL = '{}/{}/'.format(AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_URL, AWS_LOCATION)
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'


STATIC_URL = '/static/'   # <------- REMOVE
```

In addition the `STATIC_URL` needs to be prepended with `https://` and use `AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN` (not `AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_URL`):

```py
STATIC_URL = f'https://{AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_URL}/{AWS_LOCATION}/'
```

#### Why you were getting a 502 Bad Gateway error

Your NGINX and Gunicorn configurations are fine. Your Django application may not be starting correctly, for example, due to a configuration error:

To check the log:

```shell
journalctl -u gunicorn.service
```

It can also be useful to run a simple smoke test (does it turn on?):

```shell
./manage.py runserver
```

Comment: Yes im pretty sure the issue is how django is calling the static files. It's using the domain URL, and not the sub-domain where the CDN is. I'm able to enter on the web the exact path of the CDN and see the static css/js.

Also, referring to your recommended `re_path`, do I replace it with the one that's too greedy?

Comment: Change `re_path(r"^(?:.*)/?$", render_react)` to `re_path(r"^(?!static)(?:.*)/?$", render_react)` to prevent the URL from matching `static` URIs

Comment: That should eliminate the MIME type error and allow you to debug the other issue more accurately. Or it may solve the issues entirely. What app are you using to connect up your staticfiles to a CDN? Is it `storages`?

Comment: django-storages and boto3

Comment: Okay there's a couple other issues I can see. I'll edit my post.

Comment: Thank you looking forward to your edit, I fixed the URL path and that did solve MIME type issues, I'm now howeve getting a 502 bad gateway from NGINX.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231719/discussion-between-elyas-and-woof).

Answer (score 0):

In an production environment, your static files are not served through Django, but should be served directly through the webserver.

So you should configure your webserver (I assue Nginx) to serve the content of
the static directory (aka static/css/main.ce8d6426.chunk.css) directly.

Comment: Hi @schacki! So I use a CDN to serve my static files. I run `python manage.py collectstatic` to upload my HTML,CS,JS (from React) to my CDN hosted on a cloud. Do I have to specifically state NGINX where the CDN is? I thought Django automatically proxies this information because of my S3 configuration in `settings.py` (linked above).

Comment: I have added my NGINX file config in the OG post.